# Get list of COM servers

Tags: c#, windows, com

I would like to interface an application's COM server from C#. Sadly I don't know the name of the COM server, so I don't know how to get started.

Is there a way to get a list of all available COM servers on my machine, either in Windows or directly in C#?

Comment: To add a COM type from a Visual Studio C# project, just do `Reference -> Add reference`, and you'll see a list of them under the 'COM' tab.

Comment: You want programmatic way?

Comment: @linquize: The 'either in Windows' part of the question made me think not...

Comment: Study `SharpDevelop` source code `Add Reference` -> `COM tab`